# Configure up-arrow to browse through commands with same initial characters rather than all previous commands

Tags: bash, readline

On the `bash` command-line, <kbd>↑</kbd> gives me the previous command. On the command-lines in `ipython` or `matlab`, when I type a few characters, *<kbd>↑</kbd> gives me the previously entered command starting with those characters*. How can I enable exactly this behaviour in `bash`?

I am aware of more advanced ways of searching through the command-line history, but sometimes a simple way is more convenient.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The readline commands that you are looking for are the `history-search-*` commands:

> **history-search-forward**
> Search forward through the history for the string of characters between the start of the current line and the current cursor position (the point). This is a non-incremental search.
>
> **history-search-backward**
> Search backward through the history for the string of characters between the start of the current line and the point. This is a non-incremental search.

Binding these in your `.inputrc`, like so:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward            # arrow up
"\e[B": history-search-forward             # arrow down
```

will allow you to enter the first characters of a command, and then use the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys to move through only those commands in your `.bash_history` that begin with that string.

For example, entering `vi` and the <kbd>Up</kbd> would take you to the first previous command beginning with `vi`, like `vim somefile`. Entering <kbd>Up</kbd> would take you to the next previous instance, and so on.

You can read more about all of the readline bindings here:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm

Answer (score 13):

Add the following to your .inputrc in ~/, to do what you suggested:

```
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Perhaps you might also want to add the following to your .bash_profile :

```
export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why doing this "export"?

Answer (score 2):

Prepend a "!" to the command you are looking for. If you wish to replace the functionality of the up and down arrows, modifying the inputrc file (like the other answers suggest) is the way to go.

If "command" is the command you are searching for, enter this:

```
!comm
```

You should get "command" as the output.

Likewise, if you want to find a command that includes (but might not start with) part of the command, press ctrl+r and then type in part of the command.

You can also type in "tab" to auto complete your entered text (this includes files too). This is useful if you're looking for a command not in your history (or you don't have a history file)

You can read more about "mastering" the history file here:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/

This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line

Comment: The other answers answer more correctly my question, but thanks for the pointer to SO (see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/172266 ).