# Match what I've typed so far when scrolling bash history with the arrow keys

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'd like bash history to behave like vim's, i.e., if I start typing a command and then press the up arrow, it completes to the last command that that shares the initial string with my incomplete input. I think zsh does it but I'm only interested in bash.

Say my latest commands are

```
vim bubi.txt
killall firefox
```

If now I type `v` and then the up arrow the command line switches to `killall firefox`, while I'd like it to skip to `vim bubi.txt`.

Comment: Very close to a dup - [Command-line completion from command history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/command-line-completion-from-command-history)

Comment: Possibly a closer dup: [Configure up-arrow to browse through commands with same initial characters rather than all previous commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53814/configure-up-arrow-to-browse-through-commands-with-same-initial-characters-rathe)